# Magento 2.3 remove Yotpo module

Tags: module, magento2.3

What is the safest way to remove the entire Yotpo module in a Magento 2.3 store?

This module is installed and enabled by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below are 3 commands for your usage. Execute Point [1]. By using this you will get complete name of your Module, then you can run [2] and [3] commands.

1] List All Module:

> php bin/magento module:status

this will list all module with 2 categories Enabled and disabled.

2] To disable:

> php bin/magento module:disable Schogini_Firstdataglobalgateway 
>   --clear-static-content

3] To uninstall:

> php bin/magento module:uninstall Schogini_Firstdataglobalgateway 
>   --clear-static-content

ie Name of your module: `Schogini_Firstdataglobalgateway`

***If your module has dependency then you need to uninstall modules before un-installation of main module.***

Comment: if you want yotpo its `php bin/magento module:uninstall Yotpo_Yotpo`